# Get the amount of posts on a given page

Tags: theme-development, loop, navigation

When you go to something like: site.com/?cat=2&page=2

you might see 3 posts, the page before might have 5 posts. I am looking for a way to count the posts on a given page. so if I am on page 2, with three posts, said function should return 3.

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query object contains the member var `post_count` which will give you the number of posts on the current page:

```
$wp_query->post_count;
```

Also, for the total number of posts for the query (across all pages):

```
$wp_query->found_posts;
```

and the number of pages in the query:

```
$wp_query->max_num_pages;
```

Comment: Post count gives me 26 back when I only have 13 posts in total and 10 on a given page...... This is for a category. there is a maximum of 2 pages. It returns 7 pages for max_num_posts. There are 13 posts for this category....wheres 26 coming from? and the 7?

Answer (score 0):

why not do a count?

```
 <?php count( $wp_query->posts ); ?>
```

Comment: "This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content", which I am sure you don't want. Please explain why this could solve the problem.